# Sprite-kit: removeFromParent when parent gone

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Is it safe to call `[n removeFromParent];` after the parent to `n` has been released (and thus does not exist)?

I guess `n.parent` will be `nil` at that point.

Do I have to do something like

```
if (n.parent != nil)
  [n removeFromParent];
```

For reference:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/removeFromParent

Comment: I think its safe to call `[n removeFromParent];` directly bcos objective-c will able to handle this internally. However for your satisfaction you can check the parent before executing the method `[n removeFromParent];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I do it all the time. If you want to validate, simply do something like this the next time you call want to do it.

```
[n removeFromParent];
[n removeFromParent];
[n removeFromParent];
[n removeFromParent];
```

You'll notice no side effects.